# Выполнение 1 000 000 мелких заданий. Java

Tags: java, spring

Необходимо распределить работу на n часов. Выполнять работу необходимо пачками. 
Либо еще один вариант: выполнять не более x заданий в час.(Java, Spring)
Нужны советы по реализации. Либо ссылка на подходящий фреймворк

Answer (score 1):

Для таких задач создан [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/).